# uniformly convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} (\pi/2-\arctan(nx))^n$

Tags: real-analysis

I have studied the pointwise convergence and I have found the series convergent in $(0,+\infty)$. For the uniform  convergence,called $$f_n(x)=(\pi/2-\arctan(nx))^n=(arctan(1/nx))^n~,$$ I have calculated $$f'_n(x)=n(\arctan{{1}\over{nx}})^{n-1}({{-1}\over{n^2x^2}})<0$$
so the sup$_{x>0}f_n(x)=(\pi/2)^n$ general term of a divergent series.
So isn't  there uniform convergence in $(0,+\infty)$? In which interval is there?

Comment: Originally you have $\arctan(nx)$ but in the derivative you have $\arctan(\frac{1}{nx})$. Could you please check if there is a typo?

Comment: Did you try simplification by means of functional equation $\arctan x + \arctan(1/x)=\frac\pi2 \operatorname{sign} x$?

Comment: I see it now. Thanks for your hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series fails to converge uniformly on $(0,\infty).$ To see this, recall that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n$ converges uniformly on a set $E,$ then $\sup_E |f_n|\to 0$ as $n\to \infty.$ But in our problem we have

$$\sup_{(0,\infty)} |f_n| \ge |f_n(1/(n\sqrt 3))| = (\pi/3)^n \to \infty.$$

However, the series converges uniformly on $[a,\infty)$ for any $a>0.$